# Is there an API entrypoint in DS12 to upload agent into DSM?

Tags: python, rest, api, devops, deepsecurity

I am trying to automate the installation process of DeepSecurity, but I cannot find an entrypoint to upload the agent on the deepsecurity manager.
For your information, I cannot connect top the internet my installation (air gapped).

What I am trying to do is to automate this action : 
Local software upload:

[image]

So, is there any method (through rest API or legacy API or directly by dropping the .zip agent into a dictory of the DSM) to do that ?

Thank you in advance for you reponse !

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morgan from Deep Security R&D here. I've never tried this myself, but in the SOAP API there is a "softwareStore" call which "Uploads and stores an Agent software installer on the Manager". Trying that out would probably be your best bet.

There's more info on the SOAP (aka WebService) API in the SDK/docs zip file downloadable from here: https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/11_0/on-premise/rest-api.html

Comment: So glad to hear that! Since it sounds like the answer solved your problem, would you mind accepting it?